# Error: the operation '[]' is not defined for the type 'object'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, null-safety

I am using Null -Safety then I keep getting this error, anywhere I user snapshot in my code

here is the error

[image: error]

here is my code

```
StreamBuilder(
                          stream: firestore
                              .collection('interest')
                              .doc('${auth.currentUser?.uid}')
                              .snapshots(),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                              return Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              );
                            }
                            return ListView.builder(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemCount: snapshot.data!['Interest'].length ,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
                                    child: bottomCardList(
                                      'assets/1 (6).jpeg',
                                      snapshot.data!['Interest'][index]
                                          .toString(),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                });
                          }),
```

Thanks

Comment: this code is working without Null safety

Answer (score 1):

i solve this by using the type

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map>>(
                          stream: firestore
                              .collection('interest')
                              .doc('${auth.currentUser?.uid}')
                              .snapshots(),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                              return Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              );
                            }
return ListView.builder(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemCount: snapshot.data!['Interest'].length ,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
                                    child: bottomCardList(
                                      'assets/1 (6).jpeg',
                                      snapshot.data!['Interest'][index]
                                          .toString(),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                });
                          }),
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions:

- Provide a type to your `StreamBuilder`:

  ```dart
  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map>> (...)
  ```
- Provide a type to the second parameter of your `builder`:

  ```dart
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Map> snapshot)
  ```
- Use `as` to downcast the `Object` to `Map`

  ```dart
  (snapshot.data as Map)['key']
  ```